# How to rename files in a folder?

Tags: python

I want to rename files in a folder with a prefix. I tried the code below with os.rename. But i keep getting error as "FileNotFoundError". There are files in the folder '1'. Help me understand where i am wrong

```
import os

actual = 'D:/Phase2/utils/1'

for i in os.listdir(actual): 
    os.rename(i, f"{actual}1.2_{i}")
```

Comment: Have you printed i to see what's in it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the absolute path of the folder. `os.listdir` doesn't return the whole path. It returns just the name. You could join the relative path and folder path by `os.path.join()`.

While searching for relative path, python searches in the directory from where you are running the code. If it doesn't find it, `FileNotFoundError` is raised.

```
import os

actual = 'D:/Phase2/utils/1'

for i in os.listdir(actual): 
    os.rename(os.path.join(actual,i), os.path.join(actual,f"{actual}1.2_{i}"))
```

Answer (score 1):

you maybe get error because directury don't exist, you can use `try...except` like below:

```
import os

actual = f'D:/Phase2/utils/1'

try:
    for i in os.listdir(actual):
        os.rename(os.path.join(actual,i), os.path.join(actual,f"{actual}1.2_{i}"))
except OSError as e:
    print("directory do not exists")
```